# adding script tag in shopify using php

Tags: php, shopify

We are using [this GitHub PHP library](https://github.com/phpclassic/php-shopify) for adding javascript in to the head of shopify pages using script tag but we have got stuck somewhere,

it redirects well. We go to app screen to get permission also when we click on install it redirects to redirect page and gives error. in my error log.

> Uncaught PHPShopify\Exception\ApiException: script_tag - 
>        expected Array to be a Hash in

This is our app code

```
<?php
require '/home/xxx/public_html/shopify/1/vendor/autoload.php';

$config = array(
    'ShopUrl' => 'xyyy.myshopify.com',
    'ApiKey' => 'a07235d5cxx4af2239ea02fe197',
    'SharedSecret' => '7ae8a450xxxx2576cf5e7a606c3',
);

PHPShopify\ShopifySDK::config($config);
$shopify = new PHPShopify\ShopifySDK;

$scopes = array('read_orders','read_script_tags','read_products', 'write_script_tags'); 
$redirectUrl = 'https://xxxx.com/shopify/1/99.php/auth/callback';
$auth = \PHPShopify\AuthHelper::createAuthRequest($scopes, $redirectUrl);

$src = "https://xxxx.com/modules/script72paid.js";

$finalurl='https://xxxxx.myshopify.com/admin/script_tags.json'.


$shopify->ScriptTag->post(array("post"), ''.$finalurl.'', array( "script_tag" => array( "event"=>"onload", "src"=>$src)));

?>
```

and this is our redirect link code

```
<?php
require '/home/xxxxxx/public_html/shopify/1/vendor/autoload.php';


$config = array(
    'ShopUrl' => 'xxxx.myshopify.com',
    'ApiKey' => 'a07235d5cxxxxxx9ea02fe197',
    'SharedSecret' => '7ae8a45xxxxxxx76cf5e7a606c3',
);

PHPShopify\ShopifySDK::config($config);
$shopify = new PHPShopify\ShopifySDK;

$accessToken = \PHPShopify\AuthHelper::getAccessToken();

$config2 = array(
'ShopUrl' => 'xxxx.myshopify.com',
'AccessToken' => $accessToken,
);

$shopify2 = new PHPShopify\ShopifySDK($config2);


$src = "https://xxxxx.com/modules/script72paid.js";

$finalurl='https://xxxxx.myshopify.com/admin/script_tags.json'.


$shopify2->ScriptTag->post(array("post"), ''.$finalurl.'', array( "script_tag" => array( "event"=>"onload", "src"=>$src)));

?>
```

How do we avoid this error with expected Array to be a Hash?

Any help will be great.

Comment: Maybe you should raise this as an issue on the GitHub page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you are passing the correct parameters to `$shopify->ScriptTag->post()` by looking at the function in your copy of the library. Different versions of the library and documentation may have changed something.

Check that those parameters are in the correct order.
Check that all of the arrays you are passing are not actually meant to be objects.
Check if any of the arrays need to wrapped in another array.